Why is Ubuntu 22 still permitting login as root?
Running Ubuntu 22, it still allows me to log in via SSH as root-user.
I run the following configuration in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin no

Full content:
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin without-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

Running the command
strings $(which sshd) | grep -i "sshd_config"

shows the correct path for the config file:
/etc/ssh/sshd_config

Command:
ls -l /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf


ls: cannot access '/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf': No such file or
directory

> sshd -T


port 22
addressfamily any
listenaddress [::]:22
listenaddress 0.0.0.0:22
usepam yes
logingracetime 120
x11displayoffset 10
maxauthtries 6
maxsessions 10
clientaliveinterval 0
clientalivecountmax 3
streamlocalbindmask 0177
permitrootlogin without-password
ignorerhosts yes
ignoreuserknownhosts no
hostbasedauthentication no
hostbasedusesnamefrompacketonly no
pubkeyauthentication yes
kerberosauthentication no
kerberosorlocalpasswd yes
kerberosticketcleanup yes
gssapiauthentication no
gssapicleanupcredentials yes

This shows:
permitrootlogin without-password

Also, I figured out, that as a normal user, I can't login via "su" as root. But from outside I can signin via SSH.
I have restarted the sshd-service several times and even rebootet the server.
The directory
I want to achieve that no root can login anymore, only dedicated users via SSH.
How to achieve that?

The way you showed us the config doesn't prove there is no overriding rules below these. Show the complete config file. Also, what is in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d (or whatever other files included in the config)?

Also use sshd -T to dump the actual configuration that sshd is using and if it's not clear what's gone wrong from that, post the result.

I dumped the full file and added more information. Thanks for requesting this information @NikitaKipriyanov

permitrootlogin without-password allows direct root authentication with a public key, but not with a password

@NikitaKipriyanov but i tried to overwrite this in my sshd_config which seems to not work

Because, according to the sshd_config man page:

Unless noted otherwise, for each keyword, the first obtained value will be
used.

And in your config file, PermitRootLogin without-password comes before PermitRootLogin no. The safest course of action is to comment out all other instances pf PermitRootLogin before trying to set it.

ouch.... Thanks a lot!  i haven't seen this. Neither me nor VIM nor Strg-F :D
